# Pandas - split dataframe according to sorted sequence in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with this type of structure:

```
df
Val1 Val2 Col1 Col2
1    1    0    3
1    2    2    4
2    1    2    3
3    2    2    5
1    2    3    4
2    1    3    1
3    4    2    1
```

Basically, I sort the data frame according to the values of val1 and val2 beforehand, so I know I'll have two ascending sequences afterwards. 
What I want is to split this df in two new dfs, according to the two sequences, which in my example would be this:

```
df1
Val1 Val2 Col1 Col2
1    1    0    3
1    2    2    4
2    1    2    3
3    2    2    5

df2
Val1 Val2 Col1 Col2
1    2    3    4
2    1    3    1
3    4    2    1
```

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624241/pandas-split-dataframe-into-two-dataframes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177962/how-to-split-dataframe-length-wise?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't know the number of values/rows beforehand... I've also checked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467561/split-columns-according-to-sequence-numbers), so I thought about using split with a regular expression. But I only know the sequences will be ascending, there's no guarantee that the values will be continuous, so it doesn't work as expected.

Is this possible to achieve? I appreciate in advance any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Series.shift` and `Series.cumsum`:

```
m = df['Val1'].shift() > df['Val1']
dfs = [df for _, df in df.groupby(m.cumsum())]
```

Now we have each df in a list, we can access them:

```
print(dfs[0])
print(dfs[1])

   Val1  Val2  Col1  Col2
0     1     1     0     3
1     1     2     2     4
2     2     1     2     3
3     3     2     2     5 

   Val1  Val2  Col1  Col2
4     1     2     3     4
5     2     1     3     1
6     3     4     2     1
```

Comment: just for fun i was trying `d=dict([*df.groupby(m.cumsum())])` (:

Comment: Nice one, not at my laptop right now, will try later. @anky_91

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that there will be only 2 sequences? If so:

```
mask = df.Val1 < df.Val1.shift(1)
change_point = mask[mask].index[0]
df1 = df[df.index < change_point]
df2 = df[df.index >= change_point].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then `df1` will be

```
   Val1  Val2  Col1  Col2
0     1     1     0     3
1     1     2     2     4
2     2     1     2     3
3     3     2     2     5
```

and `df2`

```
   Val1  Val2  Col1  Col2
0     1     2     3     4
1     2     1     3     1
2     3     4     2     1
```